# Highlight exact text inside paragraphs generated by foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, highlight

I'm using `PHP` to import some data from `API` as `JSON` then decode it as `array` then using `foreach()` loop to print it out

**Example**

```
// comes for api or database or whatever in json format
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
foreach($decoded as $paragrah){
echo $paragrah . '<br />;
}
```

**Demo Results**

```
hello world from reddish hair Mars
hello world from my beautiful gas of Saturn
hello world from cold one Neptune
hello world from my big one Jupiter
```

Now using `JAVASCRIPT` or with `jQuery` How to highlight exact text "`from my`" in each paragraph if found to be like this image

[image]

**My Try (*Failed*)**

```
<style>
.highlight {
    background-color: #fff34d;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function highlight(text) {
      var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
      var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
      var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
      if (index >= 0) {
       innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
       inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
      }
    }
    </script>

    <div id="inputText">
        <?php
        // comes for api or database or whatever in json format
        $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
        foreach($decoded as $paragrah){
        echo $paragrah . '<br />;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">highlight('from my');</script>
```

**The Problem**

it only highlight text "`from my`" only in one paragraph once found as seen in this image!

[image]

Comment: Try https://markjs.io/

Comment: @User863 thank you for the suggestion, i might take it into my consideration

Comment: @RehamFahmy Don't use third party JS for everything unless you need something more advanced than just highlighting.

Comment: @RehamFahmy Along with below regex answers, you might also want to consider word boundaries to match words and not substring of words(this depends if you are ok with substring match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it an update of your own

```
function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(/from my/gi, '<span class="highlight">from my</span>');
   inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
highlight('from my');
```

Just need to update a single line of code https://prnt.sc/qeo45n

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking for substrings within the text as you are and trying to find the position of the text you can use a `regEx` to `replace` with a `backreference`

```js
var div=document.getElementById('data');
  div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML.replace(/(from my)/gi, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>" );
  
/* utility function to highlight `_phrase` in _str */
function replacer( _str, _phrase, _class ){
  return _str.replace( new RegExp( _phrase, 'gi' ), "<span class='"+_class+"'>$&</span>" );
}

div.innerHTML=replacer( div.innerHTML, 'world', 'lime' );
div.innerHTML=replacer( div.innerHTML, 'neptune', 'fuchsia' );
```

```css
body{font-family:monospace;line-height:1.4rem}
div span{padding:0.1rem;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:0.1rem}

.highlight{background:yellow;}
.fuchsia{background:fuchsia;color:yellow;}
.lime{background:lime;color:black;}
```

```html
<div id='data'>
  hello world from reddish hair Mars<br />
  hello world from my beautiful gas of Saturn<br />
  hello world from cold one Neptune<br />
  hello world from my big one Jupiter<br />
</div>
```

After studying the accepted answer I thought I'd show another solution which is thus far the more flexible and actually uses the input parameter for the search/replace rather than merely in an unneccessary test

```
function replacer( _str, _phrase, _class ){
    return _str.replace( new RegExp( _phrase, 'gi' ), "<span class='"+_class+"'>$&</span>" );
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer however `let` and `const` are supported by all modern browsers and we still have dinosaurs still using IE browsers :) i really would like to thank you for your efforts and well done answer.

Comment: it's easy to modify that to use the more traditional `var`